# Re-appearing login screen after updating to stretch

Tags: raspbian-stretch, login

I found several topics which describe the same issue as I have but none of the solutions worked for me so far. So on boot, the raspberry asks for a username and password (what it shouldn't) and when I enter pi/raspberry the screen quickly gets black and then the login re-appears. This happened after I upgraded my Jessie to Stretch but if I'm correct, rebooting worked a few times.

I can still login through SSH so my credentials are correct.
As far as I can tell I only added one line in my `.profile` which I reverted back already - without change.

The only hint I got so far are the following lines from my `.xsession-errors`

```
dbus-update-activation-environment: warning: error sending to systemd: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
/usr/bin/x-session-manager: 33: exec: /usr/bin/lxsession: not found
```

I'm not super experienced with Linux so I'm not sure if just re-installing LXDE would be the right thing here.

Comment: If you do an unsupported upgrade from one obsolete OS to another expert problems. Do a fresh install

Comment: At what point did I do an unsupported update?

Comment: Anyone with an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I add the same issue. 
Looks like installing `lxsession` worked for me.

Comment: What does "looks like" mean? And what do you add to the issue?

Comment: Well, I had the exact same issue. "Looks like" mean that so far it solved the issue. But I still have no idea why it solved it. So maybe there is a more efficient way of solving it.